# Redirect to child component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have fixed navbar and siderbar. But in content section i want to show list of other components & when user clicked on it, It should redirect to that component

PostAd.js -> it is one of the navbar component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import Computers from "../components/Computers";
import Mobiles from "../components/Mobiles";
import Tablets from "../components/Tablets";

const PostAd = (props) => {

    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption]=useState("");

    const onChangeSelectedOption = (e) => {
        const selectedOption = e.value;
        setSelectedOption(e);
    };

    return(
        <div className="container">
            <h4 className="" style={{alignText:"center"}}>Post Your Advertisement</h4>
            
            <div>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={3}></Col>
                <Col xs={5}>              
                  <AsyncSelect 
                  placeholder="Search for Categories.."
                  loadOptions={loadOptions}
                  onChange={onChangeSelectedOption}
                  />              
                </Col>  
              </Row><hr/>
              </div>

              <Router>
              <div>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={4}>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Electronics
                           <ul>
                               <li><Link to="/computer">computer</Link></li>
                               <li><Link to="/mobiles">Mobiles</Link></li>
                               <li><Link to="/tablets">Tablets</Link></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </Col>      
              </Row>
              <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/computers" component={Computers} />
                    <Route exact path="/mobiles" component={Mobiles} />
                    <Route exact path="/tablets" component={Tablets} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
            </Router>           
        </div>
    )
};
export default PostAd;
```

I'm getting components(computers,mobiles..) displayed on the same page with PostAd components.

I wants redirected to selected or clicked components  with its parents details

Electronics>computers and URL Route should be postad/computers

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want it so that it works for:

```
/electronics/computers
```

I think you need to add the previous prefix path to it in order for it to work.

Currently it's saying exactly/only `youwebsite.com/computer`

So you would need to change the `<Route>` to:

```
<Route exact path="/electronics/computers" component={Computers} />
```

You should be able to access the prefix with the `match` props that is inherited from react router. Try console logging:

```js
console.log(props.match);
```

That way you can do something like:

```
<Route exact path={`/${prefixName}/computers`} component={Computers} />
```

If `props.match` returns null, wrap your component with `withRouter`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const PostAd = () => {
//...
};

export default withRouter(PostAd);
```

---

**====== UPDATE 1 =======**

Click the **"Run code snippet"** button below to see it action.

```js
// main.js

const { useState } = React;
// StackOverflow only allows HashRouter
// But replace with BrowserRouter
const { HashRouter, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } = ReactRouterDOM;

const PostAd = props => {
  const handleOnChange = event => {
    props.setData(event.target.value);
  }

  return <div>
    <h2>Post Ad</h2>
    <input onChange={handleOnChange} type="search" value={props.data} />
    <p>Links:</p>
     <ul>
      <Link to="/computers">Computers</Link>
     </ul>
   </div>
}

const Computers = props => {
  return <div>
    <h2>Computers</h2>
    <div>{JSON.stringify(props.data)}</div>
  </div>
}

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  
  return <div>
    <h1>My App</h1>

    <hr />
    <HashRouter>
      <div>
      <p>Nav</p>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/postad/computers">Post Ad / Computers</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <hr />
      <Switch>
      
         <Route exact path="/postad/computers" render={(routerProps) => <PostAd {...routerProps} data={data} setData={setData} />} />
         
         <Route exact path="/computers" render={(routerProps) => <Computers {...routerProps} data={data} setData={setData} />} />
      </Switch>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

**====== UPDATE 2 =======**

After the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217028/discussion-between-codingwithmanny-and-raju-sah) and clarification, here is the revised version showing how nested routes work in the main router file and in child/sub components.

```js
// main.js

const { useState } = React;
// StackOverflow only allows HashRouter
// But replace with BrowserRouter
const { HashRouter, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } = ReactRouterDOM;

const PostAd = props => {
  return <div>
    <h1>Post Ad</h1>
    
    {/* You can continue to have sub paths */}
    <Route exact path="/postad" render={(routerProps) => 
      <div>
        <p>Electronics:</p>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/postad/computers">Computers</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>}
     />
   </div>
}

const Computers = props => {
  return <div>
    <h2>Computers</h2>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="text" name="details" placeholder="Details" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
}

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  
  return <div>
    <HashRouter>
      <div>
      <nav>
        <span><Link to="/">Nav</Link></span>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/postad">Post Ad</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <main>
        <Switch>
           <Route exact path="/" render={(routerProps) => <div><h1>Main Page</h1></div>} />

           {/* You can have multiple routes under a single route as well */}
           <Route path="(/postad|/postad/computers)">
              {/* Notice this has no `exact` */}
              <Route path="/postad" render={(routerProps) => <PostAd {...routerProps} data={data} setData={setData} />} />

              {/* Notice this does have `exact` */}
              <Route exact path="/postad/computers" render={(routerProps) => <Computers {...routerProps} data={data} setData={setData} />} />
           </Route>
        </Switch>    
      </main>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  background: #333333;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}

nav span {
margin-right: 10px;
}

nav span a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 250ms ease-in-out 0s;
font-size: 12px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
color: white;
}

main {
padding: 20px;
}

main h1 {
font-size: 21px;
}

main h2 {
font-size: 16px;
color: #666;
}

input {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

button[type=submit] {
height: 40px;
padding: 0 12px;
border-radius: 4px;
background: blue;
color: white;
border: none;
}

form input {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router/umd/react-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: i want postad/computers and redirect to computers component with computers values from postad.js component. it's displaying computers.js data below postad.js i want directly redirected to computers components

Comment: I think I got it, but just to confirm. When the user enters data, and they click /computers from the nav, it will redirect to /computer with the data from /postad, is that correct? If that is correct, then you would either need to have the state for the results exist in a higher component to pass data up from postad and then back down through /computers, OR you would need to use a state management system like redux.

Comment: @RajuSah take a look a the **UPDATE** section with working code as a example.

Comment: In your code while clicking on "Post Ad / Computers" it should go to that page, not to add that form below the "Post Ad / Computers"

Comment: Got it, but does this answer your question on how to pass that data between routes / components?

Comment: Sorry to say, but i have already mentioned it in the question. Is it possible wih react-router or not?

Comment: I think there needs to be more clarification then on what "It" is. If the question is, is it possible to pass values from other component using react router solely and not use a top level local state or state management system, then no it's not possible, BUT is it possible to pass the data from storing the data in the top level component and passing it down the routes to access it, then yes (shown in the example code above), but it would be recommended to use state management system. Does that answer you question then?

Comment: how to redirect from "Post Ad / Computers" to computers component without passing value but "Nav" "Post Ad / Computers"should not be visible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217028/discussion-between-codingwithmanny-and-raju-sah).